# Laravel get value of column from relation through pivot on load() after all()

Tags: database, laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent, relationship

I have a problem retrieving values of a column from relations in Laravel. 
I have a User - Model. This model has relation to a table btw. a model named Userhobbies.
For now we have:
`User ::: hasMany >>> Userhobbies`
Now with 
`User::all()->load('hobbies')`
 I'm getting right results like

```
{"id":"1","username":"jdoe","first_name":"Joe","last_name":"Doe","birth":"
1992-04-11","picture_id":"f3dca65323e876026b409b9ba3d49c56","hobbies":
[{"hobby_id":"1","user_id":"1"},{"hobby_id":"2","user_id":"1"},
{"hobby_id":"3","user_id":"1"},{"hobby_id":"4","user_id":"1"}]}
```

As you can see Userhobbies contains only primary-key relations between hobby - table (Hobby Model) and user - table (User Model). 
*(Hobby model also has `hasMany` relation to Userhobbies)*

My question now is - how to retrieve all hobby-names (from hobby - table) in my call over (after `load('hobbies')` ) and is it possible without writting a lot of code?

For better understanding of my idea the result which I want to retrieve:

```
{"id":"1","username":"jdoe","first_name":"Joe","last_name":"Doe","birth":"
1992-04-11","picture_id":"f3dca65323e876026b409b9ba3d49c56","hobbies":
["golf", "cards", "games", "football"]}
```

**EDIT:**

If I try following (I tried with belongsToMany in User and Hobby):

`User::with('hobbies')->get()->first()`

And I'm getting the whole values from the hobbies - table:

```
{user-specific data ...
hobbies:[{"id":"1","name":"golf","created_at":"2015-04-07 
14:15:02","updated_at":"2015-04-07 14:15:02","pivot":
{"user_id":"1","hobby_id":"1"}},
{"id":"2","name":"cards","created_at":"2015-04-07 
14:15:02","updated_at":"2015-04-07 14:15:02","pivot":    
{"user_id":"1","hobby_id":"2"}},
{"id":"3","name":"games","created_at":"2015-04-07 
14:15:02","updated_at":"2015-04-07 14:15:02","pivot":
{"user_id":"1","hobby_id":"3"}},
{"id":"4","name":"football","created_at":"2015-04-07 
14:15:02","updated_at":"2015-04-07 14:15:02","pivot":
{"user_id":"1","hobby_id":"4"}}]}
```

Same try with `->load('hobbies')`. I really don't know how to go on.

To explain it a bit more what I need one could imagine such query as follows:

`User::all(['id', 'name'])->load(array('hobbies.id','hobbies.name'))->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my knowledge, I know that it's possible to use a closure to set constraints on the query that performs the load, like so:

```
User::all()->load(['hobbies' => function($query)
{
    $query->select('id', 'name');
}]);
```

By doing it, when you cast it to array, it will produce a result near to what you want. You can even add `'pivot'` to your `$hidden` property on your `Hobby` model to hide this information.

Comment: ty for your answer. But this does not solve my problem. I want one query if possible to get last json response. Problem part is here `User::all()->WHATS_NEXT?` to get it

Comment: So basically, what you want is: when you cast a user (or a group of users) to an array, it will append the hobbies list?

Comment: I thought I could retrieve all needed user data with `->all(HERE_MY_COLUMS)` and say I want his relations to hobbies included. If I go on with every single user I have no problem to get what I need. Please see my edit above

Comment: ty, I still get such values like `pivot:...`, but I think it should do

Comment: @x4k3p yeah, that's why I suggested to add it to your model, so you get rid of it.